# onclick display none of selected image

Tags: jquery, css

How do I get a particular image to display none on click?
I am trying to set intervals to display the image:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $terror = $('.terror')

  console.log($terror);
  $terror.on('click', function () {
  $(this).css('display', 'none')
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="box1">

<img class="terror" src="assets/img/terror1.png"/>
</div>

<div id="box2">

<img class="terror" src="assets/img/terror1.png"/>
</div>

<div id="box3">

<img class="terror" src="assets/img/terror1.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, `this` is defined as `$(this)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $terror = $('.terror')

  $terror.on('click', function () {
  $(this).css('display', 'none')
  //Also, as @Ignacio Olivieri said, it would be better to use:
  //$(this).hide();
  //To display it again, use:
  //$(this).show()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1">

<img class="terror" src="assets/img/terror1.png"/>
</div>

<div id="box2">

<img class="terror" src="assets/img/terror1.png"/>
</div>

<div id="box3">

<img class="terror" src="assets/img/terror1.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

i dont understant what " i am trying to set intervals to display the image" means.

but what your mistake is

```
var $terror = $('.terror')
  console.log($terror);
  $terror.on('click', function ()
```

change it to 
$('.terror').on('click',function()